# Why doesn't my event trigger for both subscribers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've re-written the pagination plug-in, and it works perfectly when I bind to the plug-in using explicit Id's.  However, when I bind the plug-in using class-names the "page selected" event only triggers for ONE element.

**So, my question is...**

Why doesn't the trigger fire for both elements?

Just to be clear...the trigger raises twice, but the bind doesn't run twice...this is evident as the console getS written-to only once!

**THE CODE IS LOCATED AT:**
[**The JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PrisonerZ3RO/XFevk/1/)

**THE OFFENDING AREA IS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var pageSize = 5;
        $('.grid-bar-pager').pagination({
            itemsPerPage: pageSize,
            numberDisplayEntries: 10,
            numEdgeEntries: 2,
            maxEntries: 10
        });

        $('.grid-bar-pager').data('pagination').bind("pageSelected", function (event, args) {
            console.log("pageSelected"); // <--- THIS ONLY FIRES once?
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: please: use jsfiddler and reduce the code to the minimum expression: the minimum portion of code that demonstrates your point. Thanks.

Comment: Your Controller code confuses me; you trigger the event by wrapping the Controller instance in `$( )` so I don't understand how it can *ever* work ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the problem now. You're binding the event handler like this:

```
$('.grid-bar-pager').data('pagination').bind( ... );
```

The call to `.data()` will return the Controller object **for the first matched element only**. You should do that binding in a `.each()` loop so you can bind to every Controller object:

```
$('.grid-bar-pager').each(function() {
  $(this).data('pagination').bind( ... );
});
```